# mod_rewrite: rewriting environment in url in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite

I created a new environment in Symfony2 called `demo` which is controlled by `app_demo.php`.

I want to rewrite the url using htaccess tu use:

```
http://myhost/demo/
```

instead of

```
http://myhost/app_demo.php/
```

Which RewriteRule should i add to my .htaccess?

EDIT:

I was already using the way user janek suggests for removing the app.php from the url. But when i add this set of rules for the app_demo.php i still get 404:

```
DirectoryIndex app_demo.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_demo\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/demo/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_demo.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^demo/$ /app_demo.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/JnvSGhvv standard symfony .htaccess with replaced app.php to app_dev.php

Comment: do you have file app_demo.php in web dir?