# Symfony custom environment

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I'm trying to create a separate environment (demo) for demo users. It must use different database, config files and so on. I can access this environment through app_demo.php file like http://localhost/app_demo.php/route. But I want to "enable" demo environment with URL like http://localhost/demo/route.

I think I just need to play with .htaccess but I can't figure it out. How can I achieve it? Or did I choose a wrong approach and there are simpler way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863224/mod-rewrite-rewriting-environment-in-url-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your place i would just create special server/instance of application for demo. And setup it in production mode there.